# Get emmeans in sommer's mmer?

Tags: r, mixed-models, lsmeans, emmeans

> **Additional keywords:** *Best linear unbiased Estimator (BLUE), adjusted means, mixed model, fixed effects, linear combination,
> contrast, R*

After fitting a model with `mmer()` of the [**sommer** package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sommer/index.html) - is it possible to obtain [estimated marginal means (`emmeans()`)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html) / [least squares means (LS-means)](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_sect014.htm) from an `mmer` object? Maybe similar to the [`predict()` function with ASReml-R v3](https://www.vsni.co.uk/downloads/asreml/release3/asreml-R.pdf)?

Actually, I would I want multiple things and maybe it is clearer to ask for them separately:

1. **The emmeans themselves** and their
2. **Standard errors (s.e.)**
3. as a column next to the means of each level
4. variance-covariance matrix of emmeans (see `predict(..., vcov=T)`)
5. **Contrasts between means** and their
6. **Standard errors of a difference (s.e.d.)**
7. All pairwise differences between means, preferably with a *post hoc* test (see `emmeans(mod, pairwise ~ effect, adjust="Tukey")`
8. S.e.d. matrix (see `predict(..., sed=T)`)
9. Minimum, average and maximum s.e.d.
10. Custom contrasts

So yeah, basically a mix of `predict()` and `emmeans()` would be the goal here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for qdrg (quick and dirty reference grid) in **emmeans**. It may be possible to use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In sommer >= 3.7 the predict function has been implemented to obtain predictions for either fixed or random effects the way asreml does. It takes a model and the classify argument to know which arguments to use for aggregating the hypertable and come up with the right standard errors. For example:

```
data(DT_cpdata)
#### create the variance-covariance matrix
A <- A.mat(GT) # additive relationship matrix
#### look at the data and fit the model
head(DT)
mix1 <- mmer(Yield~1,
              random=~vs(id,Gu=A)
                      + Rowf + Colf,
              rcov=~units,
              data=DT)
summary(mix1)

preds <- predict(mix1,classify = "id")
> head(preds$predictions)
    id predicted.value.Yield standard.errors.Yield
1 P003             111.15400              28.16363
2 P004             135.21958              29.81544
3 P005             109.72743              29.68574
4 P006             144.98582              27.99627

preds <- predict(mix1,classify = "Rowf")
> head(preds$predictions)
  Rowf predicted.value.Yield standard.errors.Yield
1    1              81.71645              23.22997
2    2              96.79625              22.92514
3    3             128.89043              22.64216
4    4             132.65795              22.73903
```

and so on ... The RtermsToForce and FtermsToForce arguments can be used to force the use of specific fixed or random terms in the predictions. Customized contrasts I guess for the next version.

Answer (score 9):

It appears to be possible. Here is one of the package's examples:

```
library(sommer) # Version 4.1.2
data(DT_cornhybrids)
DT <- DT_cornhybrids
DTi <- DTi_cornhybrids
GT <- GT_cornhybrids
hybrid2 <- DT
A <- GT
K1 <- A[levels(hybrid2$GCA1), levels(hybrid2$GCA1)]
K2 <- A[levels(hybrid2$GCA2), levels(hybrid2$GCA2)]
S <- kronecker(K1, K2, make.dimnames=TRUE)   

ans <- mmer(Yield ~ Location, 
             random = ~ vs(GCA1,Gu=K1) + vs(GCA2,Gu=K2) + vs(SCA,Gu=S),
             rcov=~units,
            data=hybrid2)
summary(ans)

## ...
## Fixed effects:
##   Trait      Effect   Estimate Std.Error    t.value
## 1 Yield (Intercept)  1.379e+02     1.962  7.031e+01
## 2 Yield   Location2  1.776e-14     2.099  8.461e-15
## 3 Yield   Location3  7.835e+00     2.099  3.732e+00
## 4 Yield   Location4 -9.097e+00     2.099 -4.333e+00
## ...
```

The returned object has elements `$Beta` and `$VarBeta` which return the fixed effects and covariances thereof. We can create a reference grid using `emmeans::qdrg()`:

```
rg <- qdrg(~ Location, data = hybrid2, coef = ans$Beta$Estimate, 
    vcov = ans$VarBeta)
rg
## 'emmGrid' object with variables:
##    Location = 1, 2, 3, 4

emmeans(rg, trt.vs.ctrl1 ~ Location)
## $emmeans
##  Location emmean   SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
##  1           138 1.96 Inf       134       142
##  2           138 1.96 Inf       134       142
##  3           146 1.96 Inf       142       150
##  4           129 1.96 Inf       125       133

## Confidence level used: 0.95 

## $contrasts
##  contrast estimate  SE  df z.ratio p.value
##  2 - 1        0.00 2.1 Inf  0.000  1.0000 
##  3 - 1        7.84 2.1 Inf  3.732  0.0006 
##  4 - 1       -9.10 2.1 Inf -4.333  <.0001 

## P value adjustment: dunnettx method for 3 tests
```

The fact that the EMM for location 1, and its SE, matches the `summary()` intercept, and that the remaining regression coefficients and SEs match the contrast results, is reassuring.

See the documentation for `qdrg` for more details.